# javascript add active class on clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pagination like :

```
<nav>
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if product_list.has_previous %}
            <li class="disabled"><a href="?page={{ product_list.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">«</span></a></li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="active"><a href="?page=1">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>
        <li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>
        {% if product_list.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ product_list.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here my first element is active and displays in another color. 
I want to add the active class where I click.
Help needed.

I dont know much about javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(".pagination").on("click","li",function(){

  // reset previous selected li 
  $(".pagination .active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

Comment: I guess you should not assume that the OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @DamienDUPRAZ  i am not assuming.op is tagged jquery.

Comment: You 've got a point here.
The OP seems to be beginner is JS so was just wondering if he is aware about jQuery.

Comment: When I click my page numbers it works and color changed but when page reloads my active class automatically points to inital and again color changed in first page. It doesnot stay after clicking

Comment: you are saying that after reload it stop changing onclick ?? @aryan

Comment: yup when I click to page 2, at the time of clicking my color changes on page 2 but when page is loaded again page1 color is changed. it does not stay with page2 which it should

Comment: @aryan web is stateless. when page is reload previous information will be resetted.

Comment: I mean to say when second page is loaded. When second page is loaded after clicking page 2  page 2 should be active right ? Its not being that. When page 2 is loaded after clicking page2 still page1 is active. At the time of clicking only page2 has next color but when page2 is loaded it does not

Comment: @aryan you don't need click event . you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bjnLfdr8/